# How do I find/calculate the radius of curvature of a convex lens?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, curvature, lenses

I have a convex lens, and I want to calculate it´s radius of curvature. It´s focal length is 24cm. how do I do it?

Comment: You need to find out what it's made of (or otherwise find its refractive index out) then use the lensmaker's equation.

Comment: The lens is made out of glass (I took it out from a magnifiyng glass). What is the lensmaker´s equation?

Comment: There are heaps of different lens glasses of vastly different indices. If you want a hazard a guess, go with Borofloat, soda glass or N-BK7. All of which have $n\approx1.5$.

Comment: Ok, then what is the lensmaker´s equation, and how do I use it?

Comment: [This is the lensmaker's equation](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=lensmaker%27s+equation)

Answer (score 1):

You could also stand the lens on edge on a table (next to a ruler for scale), take a birds-eye view picture of it, print out the picture, and use a compass to draw a circle with the same radius as the image of the lens surface.  Then scale your result based on the scale of your printout.